# login form with java/sqlite

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jframe

I would like to create a login form for my application with the possibility to add or remove users for an sqlite database, i have created the table users(nam, pass) but i can't unclud it in my login form, it someone could help me

this is my login code:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class login extends JFrame{

 // Variables declaration

private JLabel jLabel1;

private JLabel jLabel2;

private JTextField jTextField1;

private JPasswordField jPasswordField1;

private JButton jButton1;

private JPanel contentPane;

// End of variables declaration



public login(){

 super();

 create();

 this.setVisible(true);

 }


private void create(){

jLabel1 = new JLabel();

jLabel2 = new JLabel();

jTextField1 = new JTextField();

jPasswordField1 = new JPasswordField();

jButton1 = new JButton();

contentPane = (JPanel)this.getContentPane();


 //

 // jLabel1

 //

 jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

 jLabel1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));

 jLabel1.setText("username:");

 //

 // jLabel2

 //

  jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

  jLabel2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));

  jLabel2.setText("password:");

 //

 // jTextField1

 //

  jTextField1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));

  jTextField1.setSelectedTextColor(new Color(0, 0, 255));

  jTextField1.setToolTipText("Enter your username");

  jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    jTextField1_actionPerformed(e);

  }

 });

 //

 // jPasswordField1

 //

  jPasswordField1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));

  jPasswordField1.setToolTipText("Enter your password");

  jPasswordField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    jPasswordField1_actionPerformed(e);

   }

  });

 //

 // jButton1

 //

  jButton1.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));

  jButton1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));

  jButton1.setText("Login");

  jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

     jButton1_actionPerformed(e);

    }

   });

   //

   // contentPane

   //

   contentPane.setLayout(null);

   contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

   contentPane.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));

   addComponent(contentPane, jLabel1, 5,10,106,18);

   addComponent(contentPane, jLabel2, 5,47,97,18);

   addComponent(contentPane, jTextField1, 110,10,183,22);

   addComponent(contentPane, jPasswordField1, 110,45,183,22);

   addComponent(contentPane, jButton1, 150,75,83,28);

   //

   // login

   //

   this.setTitle("Login To Members Area");

   this.setLocation(new Point(76, 182));

   this.setSize(new Dimension(335, 141));

   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   this.setResizable(false);

   }



    /** Add Component Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning) */

    private void addComponent(Container container,Component c,int x,int y,int width,int height){

   c.setBounds(x,y,width,height);

     container.add(c);

   }



    private void jTextField1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


   }



      private void jPasswordField1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){



    }



    private void jButton1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    System.out.println("\njButton1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) called.");

   String username = new String(jTextField1.getText());

    String password = new String(jPasswordField1.getText());



   if(username.equals("") || password.equals("")){// If password and username is empty > Do this >>>

     jButton1.setEnabled(false);

    JLabel errorFields = new JLabel("<HTML><FONT COLOR = Blue>You must enter a username and password to login.</FONT></HTML>");

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,errorFields);

     jTextField1.setText("");

     jPasswordField1.setText("");

     jButton1.setEnabled(true);

     this.setVisible(true);

    } else{

       JLabel optionLabel = new JLabel("<HTML><FONT COLOR = Blue>You entered</FONT><FONT COLOR   = RED> <B>"+username+"</B></FONT> <FONT COLOR = Blue>as your username.<BR> Is this correct?</FONT></HTML>");

      int confirm =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,optionLabel);

       switch(confirm){ // Switch > Case

     case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION: // Attempt to Login user

       jButton1.setEnabled(false); // Set button enable to false to prevent 2 login attempts

     break;

      case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION: // No Case.(Go back. Set text to 0)

      jButton1.setEnabled(false);

     jTextField1.setText("");

      jPasswordField1.setText("");

      jButton1.setEnabled(true);

      break;

      case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION: // Cancel Case.(Go back. Set text to 0)

      jButton1.setEnabled(false);

     jTextField1.setText("");

     jPasswordField1.setText("");

    jButton1.setEnabled(true);

    break;



    } // End Switch > Case

  }

}



 public static void main(String[] args){

  JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

 JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

 try{

  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

  }catch (Exception ex){

   System.out.println("Failed loading L&F: ");

    System.out.println(ex);

   }

   new login();

 };


 }
```

my connectDb class :

```
public class Connectdb {


   private static  Connection connect;

   private static String url ="jdbc:sqlite:data.db"; 
   private static Statement st;
   private static ResultSet rs;

   /**
 * Constructeur privé d'une connection à la bd unique
 */
private ConnectionBd(){
        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                                                 Logger.getLogger(ex.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                                 } catch (SQLException e) {
                                                                                          System.exit(e.getErrorCode());
                                                               }

    }

public static Connection getInstance(){

       if(connect == null){
        new Connectdb();

         }else{
              }
return connect;

}

    /**
 * @return 
 */
    public static void initTable(String query){

    try {
        Statement state = getInstance().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(query);
        res.close();
        state.close();


       } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ERROR ! ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                 }

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly (and by a minimum of four spaces, so that the formatter recognises it as code). This is virtually unreadable.

Comment: ...and please try to shorten your code so it's only showing the problem you want us to solve.

Comment: @Xorty: On stackoverflow, you simply have to indent your code by a minimum of four spaces. This can be done easily by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: yes I'm trying to make it readable :)

Comment: @tuxou: Select all your code, then press CTRL+K

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : thanks for hint, I just always paste it, then select with mouse and press "101010" button ^^ (I called it CODE tags)

Comment: @Xorty, I suspected as much after looking at some of your own questions, but recommending CODE tags is misleading.

Comment: @tuxou, Before selecting all your code and pressing Ctrl+K, please remove the double-spacing. It is unnecessary when formatting code.

Comment: The problem is solved thanks for no helping me :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/) and I would recommend to use [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) as database if you only use it with your Java application.

Comment: i know already how to connect on the database my problem is how to make the login form dialog with the database